# Why isn't compositing enabled by default on Lubuntu?

Tags: nvidia, lubuntu, compositing

If I have an Nvidia card and I don't have compositing enabled, is my CPU doing all the desktop rendering? 
And would it follow on that if I enabled compositing somehow, that everything on the desktop would be GPU-accelerated? I do a lot of coding so a responsive, accelerated desktop would be ideal.

Comment: You can easily enable composite in xfce settings center, window manager settings.